# How to encrypt data with a public key using RSA method from phpseclib3?

Tags: laravel-9, public-key-encryption, phpseclib

I want to encrpypt some data with phpseclib3 with a public key. The example I found on the RSA.php file doesn't showing how to do encryption with a given public key.
here is the code example on the rsa.php

```
 * <?php
 * include 'vendor/autoload.php';
 *
 * $private = \phpseclib3\Crypt\RSA::createKey();
 * $public = $private->getPublicKey();
 *
 * $plaintext = 'terrafrost';
 *
 * $ciphertext = $public->encrypt($plaintext);
 *
 * echo $private->decrypt($ciphertext);
 * ?>
```

But, I want to use my key to do the encryption.

Comment: As Michael Fehr's code shows, you load a key by doing `$key = PublicKeyLoader::load($publicKey)`. At that point you can call `$key->encrypt('...')`. If you need to encrypt using a specific method (PKCS1 vs OAEP) then you can look to Michael Fehr's code sample to see how to configure that.

Answer (score 1):

In my projects I'm loading the private and public key from a String but usually you will load the keys from a file (load a textfile in a variable should be no big problem :-).

My example is using **OAES SHA-256** as encryption scheme:

```
function rsaEncryptionOaepSha256($publicKey, $plaintext) {
    $rsa = PublicKeyLoader::load($publicKey)
        ->withHash('sha256')
        ->withMGFHash('sha256');
    return $rsa->encrypt($plaintext);
}

function rsaDecryptionOaepSha256($privateKey, $ciphertext) {
    $rsa = PublicKeyLoader::load($privateKey)
        ->withHash('sha256')
        ->withMGFHash('sha256');
    return $rsa->decrypt($ciphertext);
}

function loadRsaPrivateKeyPem() {
    // this is a sample key - don't worry !
    return '
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQDwSZYlRn86zPi9
...
3PIW4/CddNs8mCSBOqTnoaxh
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
';
}

function loadRsaPublicKeyPem() {
    // this is a sample key - don't worry !
    return '
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA8EmWJUZ/Osz4vXtUU2S+
...
QwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
';
}
```